# TCP connection not established: Can't Connect to MySQL Server on Remote Connection (10060)

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2012, tcp, tcpip

I'm running MySQL 5.6 on a WinServer 2012 system. It works great. The server is on our office intranet, not accessible to the outside world. I normally administer MySQL remotely from my office on my laptop, so I've got my user privileges set to accept my login from all hosts ("%").

This morning I came in and could not get a response remotely from MySQL. If I go to the server, the server manager shows MySQL is running (I've stopped and restarted the MySQL service to no avail). I can log in to MySQL locally from the server. Netstat shows:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:3306     0.0.0.0:0       LISTENING
```

Going to my laptop, I try to telnet to the ip address of the server and port 3306 and get:

```
Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306: Connection failed
```

This happened one time about six months ago and I ended up having to just shut down the whole Windows Server machine (cycle power). When it came back up, everything was great. This time, I don't want to have to shut down the machine (it really disrupts users of other services on the machine).

I suspect the port is just bound for some reason and needs to be released and reset.

Any suggestions on how I can make the server accept remote connections again without cycling power?

Thanks.

EDIT 1:

Based on @GioMac's suggestion, I did a wireshark on both client and server. Both showed the same thing. Here is the server's wireshark capture.

The IP address ending in `.20` is the server and the one ending in `.30` is the client:

```
NO. Time        Source          Destination     Pro Len Info
89  4.141088    192.168.1.30    192.168.1.20    TCP 66  61697 → 3306 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
143 7.137597    192.168.1.30    192.168.1.20    TCP 66  [TCP Retransmission] 61697 → 3306 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
259 13.137832   192.168.1.30    192.168.1.20    TCP 62  [TCP Retransmission] 61697 → 3306 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1
```

So, the packets are being received by the server TCP stack.

**One other big piece of info**: I've cycled power on the server hardware twice now. Still have the same problem. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried restart MySql Service instead of whole system ? Any log on MySql log files ?

Comment: Regarding restarting MySQL service, yes (see 2nd paragraph). Regarding the log, there are no errors, just notes, with the final note being `mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: 5.6.21-log' socket: ''  port: 3306  MySL Community Server (GPL)`. Notice that the socket is empty.

Comment: If you telnet the server ip t prot 3306 from your laptop does the connection estabilishes?

Comment: @Fredi, No. I stated so above in my original post, paragraphs 4 and 5.

Comment: @JonathanM sorry, you're right, i readed it as you were using mysql client. Do you have a firewall on the server by chance? Another thing i would check, be sure it's mysql that is listening on that port, see here how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows

Comment: @Fredi, please see the original post. I already did a `netstat` and it shows the service is listening on the right port. There is no firewall involved between my laptop and the server.

Comment: Install Wireshark on both server and clients and check if network packets are correctly delivered.

Comment: @GioMac, good suggestion. Please see the edit above.

Comment: @JonathanM Both server and client have TCP retransmission?

Comment: @GioMac, both server and client wireshark captures show the 3 transmissions from the client: the original transmission and two retransmissions.

Comment: @JonathanM Seems your laptop is not getting a tcp SYN-ACK from the server according to your wireshark capture. Is that all the data it captures?If so, looks like a TCP connection problem.

Comment: I think you're right. I'll re-title the question and add tags appropriately.

Comment: Looks like server is not answering at all :)
Which means, you have enabled Windows Firewall, or some part of TCP stack is stuck, antivirus might also be a issue.

Comment: Are you connected to a VPN? Is there a correct route to the server enabled? Can you ping the server?

Comment: @Gmck, there's no VPN. Client and server are on the same subnet, separated only by a wireless hub.

Comment: Can you ping the server?

Comment: @Gmck, I can ping it; I can get a response from the web service on it; I can connect using windows file sharing.

Comment: Port 3306 is being blocked, made clear by the absence of the SYN-ACK.

Comment: @Gmck, so perhaps something changed on the server Windows firewall? Is that what's most likely? If so, how best to rectify?

Comment: I can only speculate at this point, but the firewall would be a good place to start. Have a look the config to see if the port is closed.

Comment: Go ahead and put that suggestion as an answer @Gmck. I'll accept it. For some reason, the inbound rules have changed on Win Firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only speculate at this point, but the firewall would be a good place to start. Have a look the config to see if the port is closed.

Comment: No sweat. My pleasure.